# iPhone - pop multiple forms at once

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, forms, uinavigationcontroller

I have a survey app.

In my storyboard I have a series of 7 forms. The forms navigate forward with a push segue.

After the user makes it to the final form I have a "Submit" button. When the user presses this  I store the survey and then I want to "pop" all of the 7 forms and navigate back to the main form where the user begins the survey.

What is the proper way to "pop" all of these forms from the stack and go back to the main form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the storyboard is using a UINavigationController to managing the pushed view controllers you can do [self.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES] to pop all of the pushed controllers off at once.

See:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The line is actually. [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used story boards yet but, thinking theoretically. You could try something like,

[self.navigationController popToViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];

If you can get an array of the view controllers in the stack use [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]